# Can I send data (e.g. text) in a Transaction with Web3J?

Tags: transactions, web3j

I need to send a transaction from an account to another one via Web3J that includes not only the value field but also the data field (in particular, I need to send text). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is tracked by WebJ issue #[459](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/459) (currently still open).

There are two suggestions in the accompanying thread, one of which the OP managed to get to work after some fiddling.

For a normal user though, looking at the [docs](https://web3j.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transactions.html#transfer-of-ether-from-one-party-to-another) does seem to imply that an ether transfer transaction can't use the `data` field. (Neither via [`createEtherTransaction`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/ed2ca03335ad2cb3316314303746b70b456b0d68/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/RawTransaction.java#L41) nor the [`Transfer`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/web3j/tx/Transfer.java#L20) class.)